# rearranging data in excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure how to ask this question without illustrating it, so here goes:
I have results from a test which has tested peoples attitudes (scores 1-5) to different voices on a 16 different scales. The data set looks like this (where P1,P2,P3 are participants, A, B, C are voices)

```
          Aformal   Apleasant   Acool    Bformal etc
P1        2         3           1        4
P2        5         4           2        4
P3        1         2           4        3
```

However, I want to rearrange my data to look like this:

```
          formal    pleasant    cool
P1A       3         3           5
P1B       2         1           6
P1C       etc
P1D
```

This would mean a lot more rows (multiple rows per participant), and a lot fewer columns. Is it doable without having to manually reenter all the scores in a new excel file?

Comment: Are you willing to use VBA to rearrange your data?  I don't yet see a solution using only Excel formulas.  Also, if you could post an illustration of what data you currently have and what you would like it to look like it would be helpful.

Comment: @Jubbles: 70 participants have filled out evaluation forms with 11x16 scales. They have listened to 11 voices and they have evaluated each voice on 16 qualities, for instance how formal, how cool, how pleasant this voice is. I have one row for each participant, and then one column for each quality per voice, giving 176 columns. This makes stuff like One-way ANOVAs and PCA difficult, so I would like to have one column for each quality =16 columns, and then one row for each participant's evaluation of each voice, so 70x11=770 rows. And I'm afraid I don't have any experience with VBA.

Comment: @ Corbett: Oh, good! Any ideas as to how I can manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem. I just hacked this solution:

```
L         M          N          O         P         Q
person# voice#               formal    pleasant    cool
1         1         P1A         2         3         1
1         2         P1B         4         5         2
1         3         P1C         9         9         9
2         1         P2A         5         4         2
2         2         P2B         4         4         1
2         3         P2C         9         9         9
3         1         P3A         1         2         4
3         2         P3B         3         3         2
3         3         P3C         9         9         9
```

Basically, in columns L and M, I made two columns with index numbers. Voice numbers go from 1 to 3 and repeat every 3 rows because there are nv=3 voices (increase this if you have voices F, G, H...). Person numbers are also repeated for 3 rows each, because there are nv=3 voices.

To make the row headers (P1A, etc.), I used this formula: `="P" & L2 & CHAR(64+M2)` at P1A and copied down.

To make the new table of values, I used this formula: `=OFFSET(B$2,$L2-1,($M2-1)*3)` at P1A-formal, and copied down and across. Note that `B$2` corresponds to the cell address for P1-Aformal in the original table of values (your example).

I've used this indexing trick I don't know how many times to quickly rearrange tables of data inherited from other people.

EDIT: Note that the index columns are also made (semi)automatically using a formula. The first nv=3 rows are made manually, and then subsequent rows refer to them. For example, the formula in L5 is `=L2+1` and the formula in M5 is `=M2`. Both are copied down to the end of the table.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Before I click the checkmark, though, I am embarassed to say that I'll need some spoon-feeding here, I am a novice to Excel. I hope you'll bear with me for just a little bit longer:

Comment: So, I have my original spreadsheet as a starting point. Where do I want to rearrange the data - on the same sheet or do I open a new one? Then, what do I do first, the new row headers? And I gather the formulas go in the formula line above the table, right? There are 11 voices altogether, but I'll try-and-fail to see which element of the formulas need to be edited for this. sorry about being so daft.

Comment: Well, spoon-feeding you the basics of Excel is a bit beyond the scope of what I'm prepared to do, but to answer your specific points: On the same sheet or a different sheet: whatever you prefer; start with same sheet if easier, then change later. Make the two index columns first, then the rest; the column headers I made manually and have no bearing on the rest. Formulas go in the formula line above, or you can write them directly in the cell as well; same difference.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, Corbett. I'm nearly getting it to work, but not entirely. I've altered the formula slightly, to look like this: =OFFSET(B$2;$GA2-1;($GB2-1)*11) where I've exchanged , with ; (it didn't work with ,), and where B2 is the original cell address for P1-Aformal, GA2 is the cell address that corresponds to the first instance of Person#1 (L2 in your example) and GB is the cell address that corresponds to the first instance of Voice#1 (M2 in your example). I've also changed 3 to 11, since there are 11 voices.

Comment: When I copy the formula, it works across, but not down. Could you imagine what I'm doing wrong? (I hope this counts as a follow-up question, and not spoon-feeding, which of course is not something you should have to do)

Comment: This is beyond what can be addressed blindly in a comment. I suggest you ask a new question, showing exactly what is going on. The solution I suggest in my answer works fine, so from now on it's just a question of debugging your attempt to replicate it.